# Disk space management problem

Tags: partitioning, dual-boot, virtualbox

I have my pc with dual boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04. I have a a partition of 62 GB on which I created a Virtual Hard Disk Image using VirtualBox from within Ubuntu and Installed Joli OS. After I uninstalled Joli os and uninstalled Virtual Machine, I still Can not recover the disk space that was occupied by the Virtual Disk Image though I am unable to find the Virtual Disk Image. Can someone help me and tell me how to solve the problem?

Comment: Which virtualization application did you use?  VirtualBox?

Comment: Typically the guest partition is just a file.  Which host OS did you use?

Comment: I used Ubuntu as host

Comment: Yes, I used VirtualBox

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version of VirtualBox, the Virtual Disk Image files may be stored in the hidden folder `~/.VirtualBox`, more specifically `~/.VirtualBox/HardDisks`.

When you say you are 'unable to find' the files, did you try:

```
$ find ~ -name '*.vdi'
```

(assuming you used the default Virtual Disk Image type of file (i.e. '.vdi'))